# How to install ppstream?

Tags: software-installation

I googled and found many posts that says to add a repository to install ppstream.

But I haven't get a success. So how do I install ppstream on Ubuntu 10.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to add ppstream to your system either by installing the deb file which you can download from there site

- [ppstream deb file download](http://download.ppstream.com/ppstream_1.0.0-1_i386.deb)

Or you can add this ppa `ppa:cnav/ppa`

there are many ways to add a ppa source to Ubuntu which are [listed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Once this has been added and your sources have been updated you can search and install ppstream from Ubuntu Software Center.

you can update your software sources by using this command `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal or by pressing alt+f2 and filling the command in the box provided.

**Edit**

To install using apt-get install first open a terminal by either searching for it with the dash or if you are using the classic interface it is located in the accessories menu.

When you have opened terminal use this command

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ppstream`

If you see any errors please add them to your question or a comment so we can help further.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have add the ppa:cnav/ppa,but in Ubuntu Software Center->Get Software I can't find PPA for XXX. Or how do I use apt-get to install? Thank you~

Comment: I have added installation instructions to my answer.

Comment: @Allan - ppstream does not exist in that PPA for maverick :(

Comment: I suggested downloading the deb as the first suggestion. The deb is supposed to work for everything over 8.04

Comment: I tried to install from deb,and it says wrong hardware architecture to me 'i386'.(I translate it from chinese character).I remember my ubuntu is 64 bits.

Comment: I have found a tarball package setup for 64bit architecture http://dl.dropbox.com/u/971117/dev/ppstream_1.0.0-2%2Bxdg%7Eppa1_amd64.tar.gz this is about as unofficial as it gets and I would recommend making a back up of your system before testing this. To install this you need to open a terminal and use this command sudo tar xzvf /path/to/ppstream_1.0.0-2%2Bxdg%7Eppa1_amd64.tar.gz replacing /path/to/ with the relevant path. As I say this is unofficial